# Intermediate certificate missing

Tags: linux, ssl-certificate

We're using the latest `openjdk:11-jre-slim`Docker image, which is Debian 11.3 Bullseye, and we've got a a different server running a TLS cert issued by "Thawte RSA CA 2018". In our Java app running in that Docker image, HTTPS connections to that server fail because the intermediate certificate is apparently missing from the Docker image. `http` (or curl/wget) fails with `[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate`.

I can fix it by

1. downloading the missing cert from https://www.tbs-certificates.co.uk/FAQ/en/Thawte_RSA_CA_2018.html
2. adding the cert to `/usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/Thawte_RSA_CA_2018.crt`
3. add `mozilla/Thawte_RSA_CA_2018.crt` to `/etc/ca-certificates.conf`
4. running `update-ca-certificates` as root

Is this the right way to do it? Why is the intermediate cert missing in the first place, is it outdated or considered insecure...? I couldn't find anything.